# WPF Window is not set to null when closing it

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a plugin which opens a `MainWindow` from the application. I'm using C# and WPF.

```
public class StartRIR : IExternalCommand
{
    private static MainWindow mainwindow;

    public Result Execute(
        ExternalCommandData commandData,
        ref string message,
        ElementSet elements)
    {
        if (mainwindow != null)
        {
            mainwindow.Focus();
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
        else
        {
            mainwindow = new MainWindow(commandData);
            mainwindow.Show();
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is executed when I call my external application, the goal is to avoid multiple `MainWindow`to open simultaneously.

But if I close my window, I can't open it anymore. Does it mean closing a window do not set it to null? Do I have to override the `Closing` event or is there another way?

Comment: Why would closing a window do _anything_ with the reference you hold? You're not passing `ref Window` to the `Close` method so there isn't any way that could happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a manager class for cases like this. It keeps track of all registered window types and subscribes to the `Closed` event.

```
public class SingleWindowTypeHelper
{
    public SingleWindowTypeHelper()
    {
        _windows = new List<Window>();
    }

    private readonly List<Window> _windows;

    public T GetExistingWindow<T>()
    {
        return _windows.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public bool ShowExistingWindow<T>() where T : Window
    {
        T window = GetExistingWindow<T>();
        if (window == null) return false;

        if (window.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

        window.Activate();
        return true;
    }

    public void AddNewWindow(Window window)
    {
        _windows.Add(window);
        window.Closed += WindowOnClosed;

        window.Show();
        window.Activate();
    }

    private void WindowOnClosed(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Window window = sender as Window;
        if (window == null) return;

        window.Closed -= WindowOnClosed;
        _windows.Remove(window);
    }
}
```

To use it you just need an instance somewhere in your code

```
private readonly SingleWindowTypeHelper _windowHelper = new SingleWindowTypeHelper();
```

And check for existing windows like this:

```
if (_windowHelper.ShowExistingWindow<YourWindowType>()) return;

YourWindowType dialog = new YourWindowType();
// do some additional initialization here
_windowHelper.AddNewWindow(dialog);
```

or in your case:

```
public class StartRIR : IExternalCommand
{
    private static readonly SingleWindowTypeHelper _windowHelper = 
        new SingleWindowTypeHelper();

    public Result Execute(
        ExternalCommandData commandData,
        ref string message,
        ElementSet elements)
    {
        if (_windowHelper.ShowExistingWindow<MainWindow>()) 
            return Result.Succeeded;

        MainWindow dialog = new MainWindow(commandData)();
        _windowHelper.AddNewWindow(dialog);
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this works for the problem i ask but now i can open the same window several times :/

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. If this works (which I'm sure it does, I'm using it too) - why can you open the window several times?

Comment: My ` MainWindow` should be open once at a time. If i call it a second time it should make it active but not creating a new one

Comment: That's exactly what my code does. Did you use the code template at the bottom? When a window of the same type (MainWindow) already exists it opens it, otherwise you can create a new one and add that to the helper class for tracking -I'll update the code to clarify

Comment: That works perfectly now, i forgot the static, this is the only difference i see with my code, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Once you close a wpf window you cannot reopen it by default. To get round this you need to override the  OnClosing method to set the window visibility to hidden and cancel the close event.

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

If you want to stop serveral versions of your window being open at once then you could consider using ShowDialog() instead of Show(). This locks out the background application until your window is closed. You'll still need to override the OnClosing method if you want to re-use the exact same instance of your form.